# Animate div using ng-show in angularjs directive template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a message directive that show success and failure message based on values assigned to directive scope.

Markup

```
 <myslide msg='message' type='messagetype'></myslide>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('app.directive.myslide',['']).directive('myslide',function($timeout,$scope){
return {
             restrict : 'EA',
             scope:
                     {
                         msg:'=',
                         type:'=',
                         bool_success:'@',
                         bool_error:'@',

                     },
              templateUrl:'views/Msgtemp.html?1',       
              link:function(scope, element, attrs)
              {

                 scope.$watch('msg',function(newmvalue,oldmvalue){},true);
                 scope.$watch('type',function(newtvalue,oldtvalue){
                     if(newtvalue=="success")
                     {
                         scope.bool_success=true; 
 // since bool_success is set to true element is shown so no effect of next line
                         element.slideDown(1000);
// Slide Up works completly fine since element is visible.
                         $timeout(function(){element.slideUp(1000);scope.bool_success = false;scope.type=''}, 1000);
                     }

                 },true);
              }
}
});
```

Directive Msgtemp.html

```
 <div class="slide alert alert-success col-lg-4"  ng-show="bool_success">
<a href="" class="close"  ng-click="bool_success = !bool_success">&times;</a>
<strong>Success !</strong> {{msg}}
</div>
 <div class=" slide alert alert-danger col-lg-4" ng-show="bool_error">
<a href="" class="close" ng-click="bool_error = !bool_error">&times;</a>
<strong>Error !</strong> {{msg}}
 </div>
```

Now message is successfully displayed and timeout when type has value="success".

Now instead of just showing and hidding message i want slideUp and slideDown.But when i use element.slideDown , before that i had to set value of bool_success=true because of which success div is already shown , Here element.slideUp works completely fine since div is already visible but problem arises during slideDown effect. How can i achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Solved above issue using simple jquery effect

```
angular.module('app.directive.myslide',[]).directive('myslide',function($timeout){
return {
             restrict : 'EA',
             scope:
                     {
                         msg:'=',
                         type:'='
                     },
              templateUrl:'views/slideMsg.html?1',       
              link:function(scope, element, attrs)
              {

                 scope.$watch('msg',function(newmsgvalue,oldmsgvalue){},true);
                 scope.$watch('type',function(newtypevalue,oldtypevalue){
                     if(newtypevalue=="success")
                     {    
                              element.children('.alert-success').slideDown(1000,function(){
                              element.children('.alert-success').slideUp(2000);
                              scope.type='';
                         });

                     }
                     if(newtypevalue=="error")
                     {    
                              element.children('.alert-danger').slideDown(1000,function(){
                              element.children('.alert-danger').slideUp(2000);
                              scope.type='';
                         });

                     }

                 },true);
              }
}
})
```

Updated my template html to

```
<div class="alert alert-success col-lg-4" style="display: none;">
<strong>Success !</strong> {{msg}}
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger col-lg-4" style="display: none;">
<strong>Error !</strong> {{msg}}
</div>
```